# How to 'select' from XML with namespaces?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document something like :::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
          xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
          xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
          xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Worksheet1">
    <Table>
      <Column ss:Width="100"></Column>

      <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="headerStyle">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Submitted By</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:StyleID="alternatingItemStyle">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Value1-0</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
    <AutoFilter xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                x:Range="R1C1:R1C5"></AutoFilter>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

The problem is when trying to select Rows with

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//Row">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

It is not matching.  I removed all of the name-spacing and it works fine.  So, how do I get the 'select' to match Row?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Declare a namespace prefix for the namespace in your XSLT and then `select` using that prefix:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:os="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  ...   
  <xsl:for-each select="//os:Row">
    ...
  </xsl:for-each>
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This usually results in XPaths that are easy to read. However, XSLT/XPath tools generate the following, equivalent code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='Row' = and namespace-uri()='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet']">
   ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 11):

If you don't care about the namespace, you can use the XPath `local-name()' function:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name() = 'Row']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively the same same thing can be expressed like this. I'm not certain if this is standard XPath and if all XPath implementations support it (ColdFusion does, so probably Java does as well). Maybe someone knows if this conforms to any standard.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//:Row">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This QName test `*:local-name` is valid only in XSLT/XPath 2.0

Comment: This solution is a little dirty, but effective. It solved my problem too (of trying to select a slippery namespaced child node).

Comment: @Kevin Which part of it? First or second?

Comment: Sorry, the first part, I used a variation of this as an alternative to `<xsl:apply-templates select="my:node" />`. Very effective. I'm not proud of what I did, but it was a solution! (I'm aware of strong feelings around the use of 'local-name()' for matching nodes, but sometimes you just need to get it done).

Comment: Absolutely. Especially if namespace URIs are not fixed. If you only have a few possible URIs you can also register all of them and write `<xsl:for-each select="ns1:foo|ns2:foo|ns3:foo">`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm converting Adobe Livecycle 'PDF' (it's actually a moderately complex XML file) to HTML forms using XSL 1.0. So there's some pretty janky stuff going on inside it, and this turned out to be a good strategy for handling it. Specifically, body tags inside the markup: `<exData contentType="text/html"><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">`.

Comment: Well, that's a default namespace declaration. The notion of default namespaces for XPath does not exist in XSLT 1.0. Just register `xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` in your XSLT file and use the prefix like `select="xhtml:body"`.

Comment: Arrgh. Thank you, that's great, that should have occurred to me. I added every other namespace to the XSLT file, bar that one solution.

Answer (score 7):

[Tomalek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) and [ckarras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5688/ckarras) give good answers, but I want to clarify the reasons behind them.

The elements you aren't matching are in the default namespace of the scope in which they occur in the doc, that is, they are in the namespace declared for that scope without a prefix (e.g.

```
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
```

on the `Workbook` element).  Even though the tagnames lack a namespace prefix, they are in a namespace.

However, XPath requires that all names of elements in a namespace be qualified with a prefix, or that the namespace be specified explicitly with `namespace-uri()` in a predicate.  Hence, you must either use the `local-name()` function in a predicate to match the element name (and use the `namespace-uri()` function as well if there is a danger of name collisions across namespaces), or you must declare each namespace in which you wish to match elements in XPaths with a prefix, and qualify the element names with their namespace prefixes in the XPath expressions.