# XSL can't read into a xml with the tag "Document xmlns="urn:iso:st"

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, xslt-1.0, document

I need help to read into a xml file with the this definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <NbOfTxs>3</NbOfTxs>
```

The problem is that I can't read the nodes when the xml has Document xmlns... (I tested removing this line and I can read the nodes)

My xsl is this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
       <xsl:template match='GrpHdr'>
           <NbOfTxs><xsl:value-of select="NbOfTxs"/></NbOfTxs>
       </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements in your input XML have a default namespace. You need to declare this namespace in your XSLT stylesheet, too and *prefix* any input elements you want to match.

You do not need to match the `GrpHdr` elements if you'd like to output the `NbOfTxs` element and its content anyway.

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <NbOfTxs>3</NbOfTxs>
        </GrpHdr>
    </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:nsa="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">

   <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match='nsa:NbOfTxs'>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

Note that the `NbOfTxs` element still has its namespace in the output (you did not say whether you want to keep it or not).

```
<NbOfTxs xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">3</NbOfTxs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a namespace prefix for the namespace in your XSLT and then select using that prefix:
see similar question here

[How to 'select' from XML with namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/284094/1552130)